# MySQL search between two letters

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a long list of company names but I only want results where the result set will only return companies with that start with the letters A-E.

Is that possible?

Comment: What have you tried? Table structure? It is very possible to get the results but unable to answer due to lack of information.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `LIKE`

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableName
WHERE  CompanyName LIKE 'A%' OR
       CompanyName LIKE 'B%' OR
       CompanyName LIKE 'C%' OR
       CompanyName LIKE 'D%' OR
       CompanyName LIKE 'E%'
```

or REGEXP

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tableName
WHERE  CompanyName REGEXP '^[A-E]';
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*two queries*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c89f1/9)

OTHER(s)

- [MySQL REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

Comment: it is not clear if with this solution you can make use of an index on CompanyName

Answer (score 2):

You can (also) do it using a simple string comparison;

```
SELECT *
FROM Companies 
WHERE CompanyName >= 'a'  
  AND CompanyName <  'f';  -- to be sure to get _all_ companies on 'E'
```

[Simple SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc8db/1).

Comment: Seems like this is the easiest way listed to provide a range of letters.

Answer (score 1):

Company names starting with `A`, `E` using `LEFT`. If you need ending with then you can use `RIGHT` as well.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   YOURTABLE
WHERE  LEFT(CompanyName,1) IN ('A', 'E')
;
```

Comment: @Wesley check this out. It's using `IN` operator and `LEFT`. Based on the `EXPLAIN PLAN` you can choose the best fit for your needs :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE name BETWEEN 'a' AND 'e'
```

OR

```
SELECT Name FROM Employees WHERE Name REGEXP '^[A-E].*$'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE company_name < 'F';
```